# How do I disable all audio EQ/reverb/etc?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I'm in the process of writing a plugin for a piece of software, and this plugin needs to be able to write out audio.

I'm doing my development on a new Asus ROG laptop running Windows 10, and have a production machine that is an HP Z640 running Windows 7.

On Windows 7 on the HP620, when I record the audio stream using Audacity, it looks like what I was expecting. It's a square wave with two possible frequencies:

[image: Good waveform]

On Windows 10 on the Asus laptop, when I run the same plugin in the same piece of software, and record it with the same version of Audacity, I get the following result:

[image: Bad waveform]

This, to me, looks like it has either an EQ or Reverb, or some combination.

Is there a Windows way of disabling all OS-level audio manipulation?

I've been through all of the options I can find to turn things off, including Asus' `Sonic Studio II` and `Realtek HD Audio Manager`. I'm hoping that there's an OS-level way of disabling all of this and ensuring that the audio comes out of the sound card in exactly the way that the software intended.

**Edit:**

I should add, I found [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-audio-enhancements-windows-10) link which talked about turning off enhancements. I don't have the `Enhancements` tab in that UI - I just have `General`, `Levels`, `Advanced` and `Spatial Sound`. In `Spatial Sound`, the selected format is `None`.

**Edit 2:**

After following the advice @PFitz gave me to uninstall Sonic Studio and replace the drivers with the generic Windows ones, I found the following results:

1. After uninstalling Sonic Studio, the waveform was cleaner, but still not square. It would always have the initial value of the square wave, but then instead of staying high or low would decay back to 0.0.
2. Replacing the Realtek driver with the generic Windows driver caused the waveform to appear exactly as I want it when recorded in Audacity. However, neither the speakers or the headphones on my laptop then worked. The audio is hitting the device (which, I'm assuming, is where Audacity is recording from), but is never making it out into the real world.

Comment: A few things to try (if you haven't already): 1) Uninstall the Asus Sonic Studio software entirely instead of just disabling its effects. 2) Uninstall the Realtek drivers and allow Windows to install the generic Microsoft audio device drivers. 3) Try a different playback device that isn't intended to be used with any special drivers or DSP software.

Comment: @PFitz That seems to have fixed the issue internally. Uninstalling Asus Sonic Studio removed what looked like the reverb, at which point I was left with something akin to decay. Replacing the Realtek drivers with the generic Microsoft audio drivers got me to a place where Audacity was giving me the right thing, but I'm not actually getting any audio out of the speakers or headphones jack now.